# SQL: group by multiple limits

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a simple table with id，key，level，table and data are something like this ：

```sql
id key level
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   3
4   a   3
5   b   1
6   b   3
7   c   1
8   c   2
9   c   2
```

The question is: I pass in an id array(The database supports find in operation),i want only count the highest level within given id list and group by the key. 
For instance: i pass in [2,3],returned data shoule be:

```sql
key toplevel count
a     3        1
```

i pass in [2,3,8,9],returned data shoule be:

```sql
key toplevel count
a     3        1
c     2        2
```

I don't know if my problem is clearly described(not good at english), Please ask me if you don't understand.

Comment: My answer is verbose hope you can convert into logic. First filter out the rows you want using the passed in array call it table X. Then do (Select key, level, count(*) from X group by key, level) as Y.  Now use row_number function order by level in desc order and keep only 1st row.

Comment: It does work:i can use sql like this:  `select * from (select *,"row_number"() over (PARTITION by key order by LEVEL desc) rn from (select key,level,count(*) as counts from (select * from tbl_test where id in (2,3,8,9)) as idlist group by key,level) as tmp1) as tmp2 where rn = 1 ;` @karanpatel

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using, then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shall work in PostgreSQL.

```
Select * from(
Select 
    keyss, 
    levels, 
    counts, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( partition by keyss
            order by levels desc) as rownum 
from
(Select keyss, levels, count(*) as counts from test where id in (2,3,4,5) group by keyss, levels) as X
) as Y
Where Y.rownum = 1;
```

You can simulate the row_number in MySQL or I think in the latest version of MySql there should be a similar function to use.

Comment: Yes, I also got this SQL statement by referring to your comments.Any other ideas not using ROW_NUMBER()?

Answer (score 1):

I created the data similar to you and tested. It seems work for me. Please try this.

```sql
select a.`key`, a.level, count(*) as cnt 
from (select `key`, max(level) as toplevel from mytable group by `key`) b
     left join mytable a on a.`key` = b.`key` and a.level = b.toplevel and a.id in (2,3,8,9)
where a.`key` is not null
group by a.`key`, a.level
```

Comment: Did you miss something, report an error after execute your SQL in my postgresql & mysql

Comment: I modified the answer already, maybe because of the column name "key", have to wrap it in the quotes, so that it can be executed

Comment: In postgresql,error is : `ERROR:  column "a.toplevel" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 15: select key, toplevel, count(*) as cnt ` .And in mysql,it works,but data returned seems wrong when i pass in [2,3,8,9]? It return  `a     3        1,
c     2        1`,not `a     3        1,
c     2        2`

Comment: modified the answer. You can  try again

Answer (score 1):

You will replace keyValue in your key.
My table name is [dbo].[Table_2]
Please test this.

```
    select a.keyValue,a.level,MAX(rownum) as count from(
       Select 
       keyValue, 
       level, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( partition by keyValue
        order by level desc  ) as rownum 
       from
       [dbo].[Table_2]) as a
       inner join 
       (select MAX(level) as level,keyValue from [dbo].[Table_2]
         group by   keyValue)  b 
         on (a.level=b.level)and(a.keyValue=b.keyValue)
     group by a.keyValue ,a.keyValue,a.level
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Select key,MAX(level) as toplevel,COUNT(level) as count from tablename group by key
```

Max gets the highest value from level.

Comment: unfortunately it is not i want,you can not just use count(level),what i need is count of toplevel. Use your sql, i pass in [2,3],returned data is:   
  key toplevel count : 
 a     3        2